# Using jquery.scrollbar in react application

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-scrollable

I want to use jquery.scrollbar plugin in my react application. I want the jquery.scrollbar for every component which is scrollable. I have already installed it via npm. I am not getting any way to initialize it in my react component. How should I do it?

Comment: Do you have code you can share here so we can see what you have so far?  You will need to create a component and initialize the scrollbar there, likely in componentDidMount.

Comment: I can't recommend using jQuery libraries inside of react apps. It's a common source of trouble because they are interfering when updating the DOM. Try to avoid jQuery at all. There should already be solutions for this provided as react components.

Answer (score 2):

Always remember to import it in your components and called the function inside your JSX. I believe react js has some nice scrollbar which are more suitable

http://malte-wessel.github.io/react-custom-scrollbars/

Comment: When I use this, browser's scrollbar is also coming and I can see both custom as well as default scrollbar. How to deal with this?

Comment: good, and you can use react-nice-scroll it is so easy to use, and here is the link 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nice-scrollbar

Comment: @ApurvG I think I got what you meant. If you wanna remove browser scrollbar. You need to do css style changes to the container thats holding this scrolling area. try set style="overflow-y: hidden"